# JS conditional working on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage, conditional-statements

I'm making a basic web app (newbie level mind you), a text editor of sorts. Anyway, using localStorage I save the text, the font size and the font family.
All of this works, no problem. But, I have a button to toggle between sans-serif and serif, and when the text is in serif only the sans-serif button appears and of course, the other way around. This works too, but for some reason it doesn't work in Firefox using the conditional below. In Chrome works fine, that's the weird thing.

I used two console.logs to see what happens and no matter what, Firefox always goes straught to the "else" statement.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
function fontButton() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('storedFontFamily') == "'Exo 2', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" || editor.style.fontFamily == "'Exo 2', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif") {
        console.log("if statement");
        sansSerifFont.style.display = "none";
        serifFont.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
        console.log("else statement");
        serifFont.style.display = "none";
        sansSerifFont.style.display = "inline-block";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried console logging the values you're testing in the if test?

Comment: yes, on ff: ""Exo 2","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
on chrome: Lora, Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif

Comment: So what you're saying is logged are values that do _not_ match the string literals you test against, so that's why it's always going to the else statement.

Comment: Yeah but why is FF returning different values? That's what I don't get... I was expecting hing like this in IE... but FF?

Answer (score 0):

So maybe problem is in double/single quotes? It seems to me that in this case is better to use regexp testing if there is 'sans-serif' in the string.

```
if(/sans-serif/.test(window.localStorage.getItem('storedFontFamily'))) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```